# Gem, gemstone, crystal, rock, minerals image and other properties dataset

Tags: data-request, images, classification

I'm looking for datasets that contain images of crystals, gems, rocks and the like.

- My most important goal is to have the crystal name and its image so I can make a machine learning classifier for them from images.
- A secondary goal is to have its other properties, like hardness, and metaphysical properties.

Format ideally: SQL database, or something easily parsable

Have only found
[this one](https://github.com/loliverhennigh/Crystal-Gems)
with only 4000 images so far, so anything would be helpful